# Why can't I open the eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I have tried applying various methods shown on the internet to solve it but non of them helped.Others do have the same problem but not the Dosgi.instance.area.default part.

[image]

Comment: This isn't Java related it is something to do with the IDE so changed the tag. Personal recommendation would be to move to the Community Edition of Intellij if you are using it for Java. I moved away from eclipse because it kept getting random issues.

Comment: You have a 32 bit Eclipse and almost certainly a 64 bit Java. You must use either both 32 bit or both 64 bit.

Comment: greg-449 yuh thanks a lot...it works now after using the 64 bit one